# add key to proc/keys

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cryptography

How do I add a key to a keyring in /proc/keys ?

My openembedded Linux does not come with a keyctl command program.

And all I can find on google is the programming interface, but I would like to do it from console input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "console input" but I guess you want to add and remove keys from shell scripts or the command line or such.

The interface to the kernel keyring is a set of system calls such as `add_key(2)`. You cannot access system calls directly from the command line.

`keyctl` *is* the command line interface to the kernel keyring so you will need it.

Comment: Thank you. My linux kernel 2.6.32 and build does not include any keyctl command line interface. How do I get this?

Comment: http://people.redhat.com/~dhowells/keyutils/